# React Typescript: Pass value from child to parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to be able to call a function `printUrl` from the child component. I am passing the function in a prop called `theurl` I don't know how to declare this prop type, I cant leave it as `any` in the child's interface and then when I do call `printUrl('testing')` nothing gets logged. I am expecting the parent function `printUrl` to log out `testing`

I get the feeling that I've completely misunderstood how to pass values up. The error I get is `Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): printUrl is not defined`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Child } from './child';

const Parent: React.FC = () => {
    const printUrl = (arg: string) => {
        console.log(arg)
    }
    return (
    <Child theurl={printUrl}/>
    )
}
```

and the child is like...

```
import React from 'react';

interface PropsInterface {
  theurl: any;
}
const Child: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {
 printUrl('testing')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing the props here at `<Child theurl={printUrl}/>`, the **printUrl is renamed to theurl**. So, in the child component, you need to access it by name of theurl.

So, you need to access it by `theurl('testing')` and it should work fine.

Hope it helps!

Edit: Modifying the answer as per discussion. You can access it as `props.theurl` in the component:

```
const Child: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {
 props.theurl('testing')
}
```

Comment: The error I get is `Cannot find name 'theurl'.ts(2304)`

Comment: props.theurl('testing') worked, any idea on the correct type in the interface?

Comment: Try using `props.theurl`.

Comment: interface PropsInterface {
  theurl: Function;
}

Answer (score 0):

`printUrl` gets assigned to the child member `theurl`. In the child you want to reference it like so:

```
const Child: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {
 props.theurl('testing')
}
```

You can also strongly type `theurl` as a function:

```
interface PropsInterface {
  theurl: (url:string) => void;
}
```

Child is implicitly returning `void` which is can't be the return type of a React component. `null` is though:

```
const Child: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {
 props.theurl('testing'); return null;
}
```

It is good practice to name function props as a verb.

```
import React from 'react';

interface PropsInterface {
  printUrl: (url:string) => void;
}

const Child: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {
  props.printUrl("testing"); return null;
}


const Parent: React.FC = () => {
    const printUrl = (arg: string) => {
        console.log(arg)
    }
    return (
    <Child printUrl={printUrl}/>
    )
}
```

Good luck on your typescript adventures!